# How to get Client PC Printer name using C#.net

Tags: c#, printing

I am currently developing a web application to print data directly to the client's printer.  The application works well in my pc but when I post the application to our web server, instead of retrieving the printer list in client's pc, the application is trying to look for printers that are installed in the server machine.

I developed my application using C# and I am using System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters to retrieve the printer list I realised it only trying to retrieve printer installed in the local machine. The PC is not connected to any network.

Is there any way to get the list of installed printer in the client computer?

Answer (score 2):

System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters will give the list of printers where the application is hosted and i am afraid there is nothing like getting clients printer lists in ASP.Net.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan but I am trying to access the printer of the client machine.. :(

Comment: Than you should use some sort of client scripts(java script,vb script etc) which can perform such task, though it will not be so easy to implement .. :)